# How to select empty HTML tags that may have multiple empty nested tags using regex?

Tags: php, html, regex, tags, regex-negation

I would like to select all empty tags that are either standalone are are nested instead other tags. For example, regex should match this:

```
<p></p>
<p><strong><em></em></strong></p>
<p style="background: black;"><span></span></p>
```

But not this:

```
<p>text</p>
<p><strong><em>text</em></strong></p>
<p style="background: black;"><span>text</span></p>
```

In a tricky situation like `<p><span style="background-color: red;"></span>some text &nbsp;</p>`, it should match `<span style="background-color: red;"></span>`.

This is what I am using at the moment: `<[^<p>\/>][^>]*><\/[^>]+>` However, it  leaves out cases such as `<p><strong><em></em></strong></p>`, where there are multiple nested tags.

Thank you!

Comment: Is regex a requrement or do you think that's the only way of doing it so you didn't think about other possibilities ? I have the feeling a real html parser would do the job better finding empty nodes, probably with a bit of recursion involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This version should find both empty paragraphs, and empty nested tags within paragraphs. It works to a level of 3 nested tags.

```js
function emptyNestedTags(str)
{
      var match = str.match(/<(\w+)(?:\s[^>]*)?>(?:<(\w+)(?:\s[^>]*)?>(?:<(\w+)(?:\s[^>]*)?><\/\3>)?<\/\2>)?<\/\1>/);
      if (match) return match[0]; else return "no empty tags found";
}

alert(emptyNestedTags("<p id=\"id\"></p>"));
alert(emptyNestedTags("<p id=\"id\">SOME TEXT</p>"));
alert(emptyNestedTags("<p><em id=\"id\"></em></p>"));
alert(emptyNestedTags("<p><em id=\"id\">SOME TEXT</em></p>"));
alert(emptyNestedTags("<p><em id=\"id\"></em>SOME TEXT </p>"));
alert(emptyNestedTags("<p><span style=\"background-color: red;\"><em></em></span></p>"));
alert(emptyNestedTags("<p><span style=\"background-color: red;\"><em>TEXT</em></span></p>"));
alert(emptyNestedTags("<p><span style=\"background-color: red;\"><em></em></span> TEXT</p>"));
```

If you don't want to check whether the closing tags match the opening tags (and why would you, really?) it's simpler, with no need for capturing groups:

```js
function emptyNestedTags(str)
{
      return str.match(/<\w+(?:\s[^>]*)?>(?:<\w+(?:\s[^>]*)?>(?:<\w+(?:\s[^>]*)?><\/\w+>)?<\/\w+>)?<\/\w+>/);
}

alert(emptyNestedTags("<p id=\"id\"></p>"));
alert(emptyNestedTags("<p id=\"id\">SOME TEXT</p>"));
alert(emptyNestedTags("<p><em id=\"id\"></em></p>"));
alert(emptyNestedTags("<p><em id=\"id\">SOME TEXT</em></p>"));
alert(emptyNestedTags("<p><em id=\"id\"></em>SOME TEXT </p>"));
alert(emptyNestedTags("<p><span style=\"background-color: red;\"><em></em></span></p>"));
alert(emptyNestedTags("<p><span style=\"background-color: red;\"><em>TEXT</em></span></p>"));
alert(emptyNestedTags("<p><span style=\"background-color: red;\"><em></em></span> TEXT</p>"));
```

Comment: @MarkL If you have no control over the formatting of the input, you may have to add the occasional `\s*` for extra spaces.